# Cant load JSON file

Tags: json, extjs, proxy, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi I'm trying to load a local JSON file in Sencha Touch 2.
I'm using phonegap 1.4 and iOS 5, testing in VM.

Here is the code:

```
Ext.define("User", {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                 config: {
                 fields: [
                          'id', 'name'
                          ],

                 hasMany: {model: 'Order', name: 'orders'},

                 proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : 'users.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'users'
                    }
                 }
                 }
                 });

      Ext.define("Order", {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                 config: {
                 fields: [
                          'id', 'total'
                          ],

                 hasMany  : {model: 'OrderItem', name: 'orderItems', associationKey: 'order_items'},
                 belongsTo: 'User'
                 }
                 });

      Ext.define("OrderItem", {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                 config: {
                 fields: [
                          'id', 'price', 'quantity', 'order_id', 'product_id'
                          ],

                 belongsTo: ['Order', {model: 'Product', associationKey: 'product'}]
                 }
                 });

      Ext.define("Product", {
                 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                 fields: [
                          'id', 'name'
                          ],

                 hasMany: 'OrderItem'
                 });
      var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            model: "User"               
      });


      store.load({
                 callback: function() {
                 //the user that was loaded
                 var user = store.first();

                 //console.log("Orders for " + user.get('name') + ":")
                 alert(user.get('name'));

                 //iterate over the Orders for each User
                 user.orders().each(function(order) {
                                    console.log("Order ID: " + order.getId() + ", which contains items:");

                                    //iterate over the OrderItems for each Order
                                    order.orderItems().each(function(orderItem) {
                                                            //we know that the Product data is already loaded, so we can use the synchronous getProduct
                                                            //usually, we would use the asynchronous version (see Ext.data.association.BelongsTo)
                                                            var product = orderItem.getProduct();


                                                            });
                                    });
                 }
                 });
```

The JSON file:

```
{
"users": [
          {
          "id": 123,
          "name": "Ed",
          "orders": [
                     {
                     "id": 50,
                     "total": 100,
                     "order_items": [
                                     {
                                     "id"      : 20,
                                     "price"   : 40,
                                     "quantity": 2,
                                     "product" : {
                                     "id": 1000,
                                     "name": "MacBook Pro"
                                     }
                                     },
                                     {
                                     "id"      : 21,
                                     "price"   : 20,
                                     "quantity": 3,
                                     "product" : {
                                     "id": 1001,
                                     "name": "iPhone"
                                     }
                                     }
                                     ]
                     }
                     ]
          }
          ]
}
```

The alert says 'undefined', any help? Many thanks

Comment: Can you see if the JSON is actually being fetched? If you can test in the browser then look at the network tab to see

Comment: I'm trying to test it on my webserver. May take a while.

Comment: And what if the JSON is not being fetched? What could I do then?

Comment: If the JSON is not being fetched then the problem could be as simple as the path being `../users.json` instead of `users.json`. The model looks right for the JSON.

Comment: The JSON is bot being loaded, 404.
Any ideas?

Comment: How could this be? The JSON file is in the same folder as the rest of the application. Maybe I didnt fully understand this concept in Sencha Touch, but I cant fine any good tutos.

Comment: the json file is a sibling to index.html? Is the web browser giving you the 404 or is it the uiwebview.

Comment: I got the 404 in the browser (I'm now testing on a webserver).
By sibling I understand in the same folder: yes it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9153/discussion-between-sissonb-and-ricardo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sencha Touch 2 the reader object should use rootProperty instead of root.